# Collecting similar strings from local html-documents using Python's regex

Tags: regex, python-3.x, file-io, syntax, semantics

I'm having issues trying to obtain a bunch of similar strings from a bunch of text (HTML) files using Python's regex. The files in question look something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=fi>
<head>
<meta charset=UTF-8>
<title>Peruslaskutoimituksia</title>
<link rel=stylesheet type="text/css" href=
"https://math.tut.fi/mathcheck/mathcheck.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src=
"https://math.tut.fi/mathcheck/MathJax/MathJax.js?config=AM_HTMLorMML">
</script>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Peruslaskutoimituksia</h1>

<p>Kirjoita vastauksesi yhtäsuuruusmerkin jälkeen.

<form action="https://math.tut.fi/mathcheck/cgi-bin/mathcheck.out" method=post
target=_blank>
<table class=ifr>
<tr><td class=ifrl>

<p>1. Määritä luvun ` 9 ` käänteisluku.

<textarea name="hidden" style=display:none>
verbose_off
/* Tehtävä 1 */
arithmetic
f_nodes 4
1/( 9 )
</textarea>

<p><textarea rows=2 cols=30 autofocus name="exam">= </textarea>
<textarea name="hidden" style=display:none>end_of_answer</textarea>

<input type=submit formtarget=feedback1 value="submit, to the right">
</td><td class=ifrr>
<iframe name=feedback1 height=200></iframe></td></tr>
</table>
</form>

<form action="https://math.tut.fi/mathcheck/cgi-bin/mathcheck.out" method=post
target=_blank>
<table class=ifr>
<tr><td class=ifrl>

<p>2. Määritä luvun ` -4 ` vastaluku.

<textarea name="hidden" style=display:none>
verbose_off
/* Tehtävä 2 */
arithmetic
f_nodes 2
(-1)*( -4 )
</textarea>

<p><textarea rows=2 cols=30 name="exam">= </textarea>
<textarea name="hidden" style=display:none>end_of_answer</textarea>

<input type=submit formtarget=feedback2 value="submit, to the right">
</td><td class=ifrr>
<iframe name=feedback2 height=200></iframe></td></tr>
</table>
</form>

<form action="https://math.tut.fi/mathcheck/cgi-bin/mathcheck.out" method=post
target=_blank>
<table class=ifr>
<tr><td class=ifrl>

<p>3. Laske lausekkeen ` 7 /d^ 3 + 4 ` arvo, kun `d=3`. Anna vastaus
kokonaislukuna tai murtolukuna `a/b`, missä `a` ja `b` ovat kokonaislukuja.

<textarea name="hidden" style=display:none>
verbose_off
/* Tehtävä 3 */
arithmetic
f_nodes 3
7 /3^ 3 + 4
</textarea>

<p><textarea rows=2 cols=30 name="exam">= </textarea>
<textarea name="hidden" style=display:none>end_of_answer</textarea>

<input type=submit formtarget=feedback3 value="submit, to the right">
</td><td class=ifrr>
<iframe name=feedback3 height=200></iframe></td></tr>
</table>
</form>

<form action="https://math.tut.fi/mathcheck/cgi-bin/mathcheck.out" method=post
target=_blank>
<table class=ifr>
<tr><td class=ifrl>

<p>4. Laske lausekkeen `x^ 4 + x^ 3 ` arvo, kun `x = 3`.

<textarea name="hidden" style=display:none>
verbose_off
/* Tehtävä 4 */
arithmetic
f_nodes 1
3^ 4 + 3^ 3
</textarea>

<p><textarea rows=2 cols=30 name="exam">= </textarea>
<textarea name="hidden" style=display:none>end_of_answer</textarea>

<input type=submit formtarget=feedback4 value="submit, to the right">
</td><td class=ifrr>
<iframe name=feedback4 height=200></iframe></td></tr>
</table>
</form>

<form action="https://math.tut.fi/mathcheck/cgi-bin/mathcheck.out" method=post
target=_blank>
<table class=ifr>
<tr><td class=ifrl>

<p>5. Laske lausekkeen `( 8 )/( 5 ): ( 2 )/( 3 )` arvo murtolukuna `a/b`, missä
`a` ja `b` ovat kokonaislukuja.

<textarea name="hidden" style=display:none>
verbose_off
/* Tehtävä 5 */
arithmetic
f_nodes 3
(( 8 )/( 5 ))/(( 2 )/( 3 ))
</textarea>

<p><textarea rows=2 cols=30 name="exam">= </textarea>
<textarea name="hidden" style=display:none>end_of_answer</textarea>

<input type=submit formtarget=feedback5 value="submit, to the right">
</td><td class=ifrr>
<iframe name=feedback5 height=200></iframe></td></tr>
</table>
</form>

<hr>
<p class=unimp>This file was generated 2018-07-06 11:23:11 UTC.

</body>
</html>
```

The specific strings I'm trying to obtain are the ones contained between the tags

```
<p>(some number). ...</textarea>,
```

for example

```
<p>1. Määritä luvun ` 9 ` käänteisluku.

<textarea name="hidden" style=display:none>
verbose_off
/* Tehtävä 1 */
arithmetic
f_nodes 4
1/( 9 )
</textarea>
```

However, calling Python's regex's `findall`-function as follows

```
"""
Reading the assignments into memory from the produced HTML-files
"""
htmlDirEntries = sorted([filename for filename in os.listdir("./HTMLfiles") if filename.endswith(".html")])
# print(htmlDirEntries)

HTMLdict = {}
for filename in htmlDirEntries:
    print(f"Copying contents of {filename}...")
    with open(f"./HTMLfiles/{filename}", 'r') as f:
        filecontents = f.read()
        HTMLdict[filename] = filecontents
    print("Done.")

print()

print("Looking for and collecting assignments...")
print()

for filename in HTMLdict:
    print(filename)
    assignments = re.findall("<p>\d.+.*</textarea>", HTMLdict[filename], re.DOTALL)
    i = 1
    for assignment in assignments:
        print(f"Assignment {i}")
        i += 1
        print(assignment)

print("Done.")
```

does not return the desired output, which should be a list of strings looking something like this:

```
'<p>1. Määritä luvun ` 7 ` käänteisluku.\n\n<textarea name="hidden" style=display:none>\nverbose_off\n/* Tehtävä 1 */\narithmetic\nf_nodes 4\n1/( 7 )\n</textarea>'
```

What is returned instead is the contents of the entire file starting from the first `<p>1. ...`. I'm guessing my use of `re.findall` is not correct.

What I'm wondering is, why does the `findall`-method not return the string ending at the first `</textarea>` after the starting `<p>`? What am I doing wrong here? My first inkling would be to look at the regular expression given to `findall`, namely `"<p>\d.+.*</textarea>"`...

### EDIT:

The following expression returns what I want, although it doesn't work in all cases:

```
assignments = re.findall(r"<p>\d+.+\n\n.+\n.+\n.+\n.+\n.+\n.+\n</textarea>", HTMLdict[filename])
```

With some files this returns an empty list, even though I'm pretty sure they have the same format.

### EDIT2

Turns out the files didn't have the same format. There are extra newlines in some of the files between the starting `<p>`-tag and `<textarea...`

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this had everything to do with the *greediness* of the `*`- and `+`-operators. Adding a ?-operator after either of those fixed the issue:

```
assignments = re.findall("<p>\d+.[\s\S]+?</textarea>", HTMLdict[filename])
```

Here the expression `[\s\S]` refers to all possible characters, including newlines. I wanted as many of these as possible, while at the same time receiving as few `</textarea>`-tags as possible, which required the use of the limiting `?`-operator.